# Postgres statement for JSON_VALUE

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

what is the postgres statement for this SQL statement.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 where JSON_VALUE(colB,'$.Items[0].Item') ='abc'
```

i have tried follow postgres document but result 
No function matches the given name and argument types

Comment: everything is here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-json.html

Comment: tried but not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`->` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) to access an element in an index.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
where colb -> 'Items' -> 0 ->> 'Item' = 'abc'
```

`colb -> 'Items' -> 0` returns the first array element of `Items` as a JSON value. And `->> 'Item'` then returns the key `"Item"` from within that JSON as a `text` (aka varchar) value.

This requires that `colb` is defined as `jsonb` (or at least `json`). If not, you need to cast it like this `colb::jsonb`. 
But in the long run you should really convert that column to `jsonb` then.

---

If you want to search for `Item = 'abc'` *anywhere* in the `Items` array (not just position 0), you can use the `@>` operator:

```
select *
from data
where colb @> '{"Items": [{"Item": "abc"}]}';
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/BQWB24156

The above can use a GIN index on the column `colb`. The first query will require an index on *that* expression.

---

With Postgres 12 you can use a JSON path query like you have:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
where jsonb_path_exists(colb, '$.Items[0].Item' ? (@ == "abc")');
```

If you want to search anywhere in the array, you can use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
where jsonb_path_exists(colb, '$.Items[*].Item' ? (@ == "abc")');
```

That again can not make use of a GIN index on the column, it would require an index on *that* expression

Answer (score 1):

Something like this.

```
SELECT t.*
     FROM table1  t
    cross join json_array_elements(colb->'Items') as j
where j->>'Item' = 'abc'
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=610c9768ab94ede5d7da46804725238b)

Comment: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text -> unknown
LINE 3:     cross join json_array_elements(colb->'Items') as j
                                                   ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: i saw your demo, i do not need to further process that column. just simple like sql query, display the row record.

Comment: @user12158726 : what's the datatype of colB? It should be json, otherwise you need to cast it.

Comment: the datatype is nvarchar , json strings stored there